# Correct WAVE_FORMAT_1S16 PCM dual-channel format?

Tags: audio, windows-10

I am trying to play 2 16-bit PCM streams on Windows 10 WinMM Audio,
each on a separate channel, using this WAVEFORMATEX :

```
const WAVEFORMATEX
  _wex_  = // (WAVEFORMATEX)
 { .wFormatTag     = WAVE_FORMAT_PCM
 , .nChannels      = 2
 , .nSamplesPerSec = 8000
 , .nAvgBytesPerSec= 16000
 , .nBlockAlign    = 4
 , .wBitsPerSample = 16
 , .cbSize         = 0
 };
```

When I play them with 2 processes, process A laying out its stream like:

```
   Bit 31:              |                 :Bit 0
          <PCM_16_BITS> |    00   ...    00
```

and process B laying out its stream like:

```
   Bit 31:              |                 :Bit 0
          00  ...   00  |    <PCM_16_BITS>
```

, then the stream plays on left and right channels successfully (is Mixed
by the WAS Mixer device - each stream plays on only one channel so is played only
on left or right speaker ).

But if I write a single process which combines the two streams, so that
a single stream is laid out like:

```
   Bit 31:                   |                     :Bit 0
          <LEFT PCM_16_BITS> | <RIGHT PCM_16_BITS>
```

then the stream plays as garbled nonsense.

Please could anyone enlighten me as to the actual byte layout that Windows Audio
expects the frames to have for 2-channel 16-bit PCM as configured by my WAVEFORMATEX ?

I have written the code to invoke waveOutOpen, waveOutPrepareHeader, and waveOutWrite, etc., which works fine, it is just when I try to
play a combined stream with the 2 left|right 16-bit audio samples laid out in
high 16 bits and low 16 bits of 32-bit words that the output is garbled -
I guess I just do not know what format Windows Audio is expecting here.

Or is my WAVEFORMATEX in error somehow?

Or point to where this might be documented ? The Microsoft docs go into excruciating detail on header file contents without actually explaining things like stream layouts at all.

Thanks in advance for any helpful advice / replies.

Comment: It would be nice to have for WAS something similar to ALSA
(https://www.alsa-project.org/wiki/FramesPeriods), where it states :
"
Say we want to work with a stereo, 16-bit, 44.1 KHz stream, one-way (meaning, either in playback or in capture direction). Then we have:

    'stereo' = number of channels: 2
    1 analog sample is represented with 16 bits = 2 bytes
    1 frame represents 1 analog sample from all channels; here we have 2 channels, and so:
        1 frame = (num_channels) * (1 sample in bytes) = (2 channels) * (2 bytes (16 bits) per sample) = 4 bytes (32 bits)
"

Comment: So the ALSA docs suggest that left|right 16-bit PCM should be laid out in a 32-bit word as I am doing & is shown above, but WAS does not like this - do I have to use 8 bytes , with 2 16-bit words in 2 low-16 bits of the 2 32-bit words ?

Answer (score 0):

Aha! I finally found :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/ksmedia/ns-ksmedia-waveformatextensible

and

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/ksmedia/ns-ksmedia-ksaudio_channel_config

which do answer the question - I guess if I am sending 2 channels
in one frame I have to use 12 bytes per channel .

Answer (score 0):

OK, the last answer wasn't really an answer - here is a better attempt -

To save anyone else the headaches I have been through the last few days,
here is the corrected 'pwfx' waveOutOpen parameter:

```
const WAVEFORMATEXTENSIBLE
  _wex_ext_ =
  { .Format =
    { .wFormatTag     = WAVE_FORMAT_EXTENSIBLE
    , .nChannels      = 2
    , .nSamplesPerSec = 8000
    , .nAvgBytesPerSec= 32000
    , .nBlockAlign    = 4
    , .wBitsPerSample = 16
    , .cbSize         = sizeof(WAVEFORMATEXTENSIBLE) - 
                      sizeof(WAVEFORMATEX)
   }
 , .Samples       = {16}
 , .dwChannelMask = (SPEAKER_FRONT_LEFT | SPEAKER_FRONT_RIGHT)
 , .SubFormat = DEFINE_WAVEFORMATEX_GUID(WAVE_FORMAT_PCM)
 };
```

So if that is used as the structure to which 'pwfx' points :

```
  switch
  ( r =
    waveOutOpen
    ( &aoh        // Audio Output Handle
    , WAVE_MAPPER
    , ((WAVEFORMATEX*)&_wex_ext_) 
    , ((DWORD_PTR)waveOutProc) // Callback function on WOM_DONE
    , ((DWORD_PTR)0UL)         // no user paramet
    , WAVE_FORMAT_DIRECT | CALLBACK_FUNCTION // do not modify audio data
    )
  )
  {case MMSYSERR_NOERROR:
    break;
   case MMSYSERR_ALLOCATED:
    ok   = false;
    emsg = "Specified resource is already allocated.";
    break;
   case MMSYSERR_BADDEVICEID:
    ok   = false;
    emsg = "Specified device identifier is out of range.";
    break;
   case MMSYSERR_NODRIVER:
    ok   = false;
    emsg = "No device driver is present.";
    break;
   case MMSYSERR_NOMEM:
    ok   = false;
    emsg = "Unable to allocate or lock memory.";
    break;
   case WAVERR_BADFORMAT:
    ok   = false;
    emsg = "Attempted to open with an unsupported waveform-audio format.";
    break;
   case WAVERR_SYNC:
    ok   = false;
    emsg = "The device is synchronous but waveOutOpen was called without using the WAVE_ALLOWSYNC flag.";
    break;
   default:
    ok = false;
    if ( 0 == waveOutGetErrorText(r, ((u8_t*) &pcm[0].l[0]), 1024 ))
    { u16_t len = 1024;
      s8_t *str = ((s8_t*)&pcm[0].l[0]);
      utf8str( ((u16_t*)&pcm[0].l[0]), wcslen((U16_t*)&pcm[0].l[0]), &str, &len);
      emsg = ((const char*) &pcm[0].l[0]);
    }
    break;
  }
```

Then either of the two SINGLE CHANNEL formats played by 2 processes:

```
                   Bit:15
 Bit: 31:               |                    Bit: 0:
       <16-bit LE PCM L>| 0           ...         0   # all zeros, OR:

                   Bit:15
 Bit: 31:               |                    Bit: 0:
       0      ...      0|       <16-bit LE PCM R>  |
```

works fine, and mixes so that "PCM L" plays on LEFT channel, and PCM R
plays on RIGHT channel,

But I have had no NO success playing this with a single process :

```
                               Bit:15
 Bit: 31:                           |                    Bit:    0:
      <1|       <16-bit LE PCM L>  | <16-bit LE PCM R>
```

The same occurs when playing the stream with ALSA (alsa-lib) on Linux -
so it is not a windows thing.

On Linux, with ALSA's S16_LE format,
I have tried playing the same streams, in one process,  like:

```
                    Bit:15
  Bit: 31:               |                    Bit: 0:
        <16-bit LE PCM L>| 0           ...         0   # all zeros 
        0      ...      0|       <16-bit LE PCM R>
```

I have also tried:

```
                    Bit:15
  Bit: 31:               |               Bit: 0:
        0      ...      0|    <16-bit LE PCM L>|   
        0      ...      0|    <16-bit LE PCM R>|
```

and:

```
                    Bit:15
  Bit: 31:               |               Bit: 0:
        <16-bit LE PCM L>|   0       ...      0| 
        <16-bit LE PCM R>|   0       ...      0|
```

But these also donot work (the stream is full of clicks & glitches
and the signals seem to alternate between Left & Right & are barely
audible).  Of course, how could that work if I've specified the
S16_LE format, which expects 16-bit frames , and I'm writing 32-bit
frames ?

So, I'm really stuck as to what the exact interleaving byte format
should be.

On Windows, the code doing the interleaving looks like:

```
  typedef struct pcm_frame_s
  { U16_t l[320], r[320], lr[640];
  } PCMFrame_t;

  static
    PCMFrame_t pcm[16] = {0};
  

  ...
  // pcmA & pcmB are pointers to pcm[i].l[0] & pcm[i].r[0] :
  if ( pcmA && pcmB )
     { register U8_t
        np;
      register U16_t
        *ppcm  =&pcm[i].lr[0];
      for( np = 0
         , pcmA=&pcm[i].l[0]
         , pcmB=&pcm[i].r[0]
         ; np < 160
         ; ++np, ++ppcm, ++pcmA, ++pcmB
         )
      { *ppcm   = *pcmA ? *pcmA : pcm_slnc[np];
        ppcm   += 1;
        *ppcm   = *pcmB ? *pcmB : pcm_slnc[np];
      } // pcm_slnc is a pre-computed "Comfort Noise" block
    
    }else
    { register U8_t
        np;
      register U16_t
        *ppcm  = &pcm[i].lr[0]
      , *pspcm = pcmA ? pcmA : pcmB;
      if(left) // user has chosen to put 1st stream on left channel
      {
        for(np=0; np < 160; ++np, ++ppcm, ++pspcm)
        { *ppcm = *pspcm;
          ppcm += 1;
          *ppcm = pcm_slnc[np];
        }    
      } else
      {
        for(np=0; np < 160; ++np, ++ppcm, ++pspcm)
        { *ppcm = pcm_slnc[np];
          ppcm += 1;
          *ppcm=*pspcm;
        }
      }
    }            
    while (  (WHDR_PREPARED | WHDR_DONE) 
          != (wh[i].dwFlags & (WHDR_PREPARED | WHDR_DONE)) 
          )
    { if (!WaitOnAddress
           ( &(wh[i].dwFlags)
           , &playingDwFlags
           , sizeof(u32_t)
           , INFINITE
           )
         )
      { say(FMT("WaitOnAddress failed in INFINITE mode."));
        ok = false;
        break;
      }
    }
    wh[i].dwFlags &= ~WHDR_DONE;
    switch
    ( r = waveOutWrite(aoh, &wh[i], sizeof(wh[i])) )
    {case MMSYSERR_NOERROR:
    ...
```

I think I MUST specify 32-bits per channel, and use a 32-bit frame size?

So there is no way I can  interleave two 16-bit left | right channel
PCM values next to each other without using a 32-bit stream format ?

I am on the verge of giving up and just using 2 processes and the
mixer, which strangely DOES honor the "<left 16 bits>|0" (left process) and
"0|<right 16-bits>" (right process) (left | right) channel format
and send them to the left / right speakers as expected.

But there is no way to specify two 16-bit channels in a 32-bit word?
Strange.